# Azure DevOps service hook - "build for ![repo item].... ![Branch icon]"

Tags: azure-devops

I've just set up a service hook for one of the projects in our on-site DevOps server, that uses a "Incoming Webhook" connector to an Outlook Group.
The hook seems to work fine - I'm getting the notifications I'm expecting through just fine. However, there seems to be an issue with what I assume is supposed to be graphics.

For example, for the "build succeeded" service hook, I receive the following email:

[image: Azure WebHook image 1]

Looking at the status message, it states:

```
"Build for !Repo Icon.... !Branch Icon..."
```

I assume these are SUPPOSED to be images, but I can't figure out why they're not being shown as such?

Examining the request JSON that is sent from DevOps to Office 365, I can see it's passing through that specific text, but I think its being perceived as a link markdown, rather than an image:

```
"text": "Build for ![Repo Icon](https://cdn.vsassets.io/content/notifications/teams-pushrepo.png) [JamalHartnettUserBranch](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/_git/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766) ![Branch Icon](https://cdn.vsassets.io/content/notifications/teams-branch.png) [master](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/_git/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766/#version=GBmaster), finished 04/07/2015 17:24:20 UTC"
```

Anyone have an idea how I'd fix this?
I know there's a specific Azure DevOps connector, but that only works with cloud-based DevOps instances, not private on-site ones (at least, as far as I can tell)

For reference, here's the full json request message (with private urls removed):

```
Method: POST
URI: https://outlook.office.com/webhook/<obfuscated>/IncomingWebhook/<obfuscated>/<obfuscated>
HTTP Version: 1.1
Headers:
{
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
Content:
{

    "sender": "Azure DevOps Services",

    "summary": "Build 20150407.2 - succeeded",

    "themeColor": "#107c10",

    "title": null,

    "text": null,

    "sections": [{

        "title": null,

        "markdown": true,

        "images": null,

        "activityTitle": "[CustomerAddressModule / 20150407.2](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766/_apis/build/Builds/1) (Succeeded)",

        "activitySubtitle": "Trigger: batchedCI for [Jamal Hartnett](mailto:Jamal.Hartnett@Fabrikamcloud.com)",

        "text": "Build for ![Repo Icon](https://cdn.vsassets.io/content/notifications/teams-pushrepo.png) [JamalHartnettUserBranch](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/_git/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766) ![Branch Icon](https://cdn.vsassets.io/content/notifications/teams-branch.png) [master](https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/_git/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766/#version=GBmaster), finished 04/07/2015 17:24:20 UTC",

        "activityImage": "https://cdn.vsassets.io/content/notifications/teams-build-succeeded.png",

        "activityImageType": "article"

        }],

    "potentialAction": [{

        "@context": "http://schema.org",

        "@type": "ViewAction",

        "name": "View build",

        "target": [

            "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/71777fbc-1cf2-4bd1-9540-128c1c71f766/_apis/build/Builds/1"]

    }]

}
```

Comment: I'm supposing your images should go in `sections > images` to be rendered when the notification is displayed, as the other image that is correctly displayed is in `activityImage` property. However, I'm not sure if you have control of adding them there when the notification is sent from DevOps.